# updating database records using waterline orm, mongodb and async.parallel

Tags: node.js, waterline, hapi.js, async.js

I am nodejs developer. I am using Mongodb with waterline ORM and async lib for performing a update tasks. below are the steps i am following

```
function update(task, payload, next) {
    const self = this; 

    async.auto({
        createUpdateObj : (callback) => {
            let update = { status : payload.status };

            return callback(null, update);
        },
        updateTask : ['createUpdate', (result, callback) => {
            self.waterline.collections.task.update(task.id, result.creatUpdateObj, callback);
        }]
    }, (err, results) => {
        if(err) return next(err);

        return next(null, { message : "Task updated successfully." });
    });
}

let dbTasks = [ { id : 1, name : 'Testing', status : 'To Do' }, { id : 2, name : 'Development', status : 'In Progress' } ]

let asyncTasks = [];

let payload = {
    tasks = [{ id : 1, status : 'Done'}, {id : 2, status : 'Testing'}]
};

dbTasks.forEach((task, index) => {
    asyncTasks.push(function(cb) {

        update.bind(hapiServerObject)(task, payload.tasks[index], cb)
    });
});

async.parallel(asyncTasks, console.log); // It prints the response message 2 times.
```

Above is the code. Code works as expected but only issue i am facing is, Every task status in database gets updated to 'Testing'. That means, last database update query updates all the other statuses.

After the update query, the expected result should be

```
[ { id : 1, name : 'Testing', status : 'Done' }, { id : 2, name : 'Development', status : 'Testing' } ]
```

Actual Result is

```
[ { id : 1, name : 'Testing', status : 'Testing' }, { id : 2, name : 'Development', status : 'Testing' } ]
```

I am not getting where i am going wrong. I know its related to referencing of object but i cannot find where the refrence get changed. Before the query gets executed the object forming is ok.

Tools used :-
hapijs, waterline -> 0.11, async module and mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer. Code is working properly. The issue is, before updating task, I use native waterline query through which i get "_id" of the record from mongodb. Waterline does not understand the value of "_id" received from the the result of native query.
So waterline update query becomes
From

```
waterline.collections.collection.update({ id : _id }, { status : "Testing" }).exec()
```

To

```
waterline.collections.collection.update({}, { status : "Testing" }).exec()
```

And thus, all records get updated with the status of last db query.